# Python chaining decorators overwrite attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

I have two decorators. Each decorator gets a function as an argument. Each decorator sets an attribute to the function. After chaining the decorators on a single function, I would expect to see 2 new attributes. However, the top decorator t2 "overwrites" the attributes t1 sets. In otherwise, t1 no longer exists after everything is resolved. Can anyone explain why and how to fix it?

```
def t1(function):
 def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
  setattr(wrapper, "t1", True)
  return function(*args, **kwargs)
 setattr(wrapper, "t1", False)
 return wrapper

def t2(function):
 def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
  setattr(wrapper, "t2", True)
  return function(*args, **kwargs)
 setattr(wrapper, "t2", False)
 return wrapper

@t2
@t1
def test():
 pass
```

Comment: `t1` "wraps" the function `test`, and then `t2` "wraps" the function returned by `t1`. Therefore `t2` should expect a *decorated* function as its parameter — not `test`.

Comment: As a stylistic side point, [the PEP8 standard](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) calls for 4 spaces for indentation. While just 1 works syntactically, it's really hard to read, and makes it hard to share your code with others.

Comment: Yes, I see that is the case. If I dir(function) the input of t2, I see the attributes t1. However, if I dir(test), I only see t2 (t1 is erased).

Comment: Sorry about the indents, I'm working on a tiny monitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens, because your decorators set attributes on wrappers. When the first decorated sets the attribute on its wrapper, it passes the wrapper to the second decorater, that adds another wrapper on top of the first one and sets the attribute on the second wrapper. So you end up with the second wrapper.

```
In [3]: def decorator_a(fn):
   ...:     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
   ...:         return fn(*args, **kwargs)
   ...:     print("I'm setting the attribute on function {}".format(id(wrapper)))
   ...:     setattr(wrapper, "attr1", True)
   ...:     return wrapper
   ...: 

In [4]: def decorator_b(fn):
   ...:     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
   ...:         return fn(*args, **kwargs)
   ...:     print("I'm setting the attribute on function {}".format(id(wrapper)))
   ...:     setattr(wrapper, "attr2", True)
   ...:     return wrapper
   ...: 

In [5]: first_time_decorated = decorator_a(lambda x: x)
I'm setting the attribute on function 4361847536

In [6]: second_time_decorated = decorator_b(first_time_decorated)
I'm setting the attribute on function 4361441064
```

You can solve this by setting all attributes of a function being decorated on the wrapper

```
In [14]: def decorator_a(fn):
    ...:     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    ...:         return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    ...:     setattr(wrapper, "attr1", True)
    ...:     for attribute in set(dir(fn)) - set(dir(wrapper)):
    ...:         setattr(wrapper, attribute, getattr(fn, attribute))
    ...:     return wrapper
    ...: 

In [15]: def decorator_b(fn):
    ...:     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    ...:         return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    ...:     setattr(wrapper, "attr2", True)
    ...:     for attribute in set(dir(fn)) - set(dir(wrapper)):
    ...:         setattr(wrapper, attribute, getattr(fn, attribute))
    ...:     return wrapper
    ...: 

In [16]: first_time_decorated = decorator_a(lambda x: x)

In [17]: second_time_decorated = decorator_b(first_time_decorated)

In [18]: second_time_decorated.attr1
Out[18]: True

In [19]: second_time_decorated.attr2
Out[19]: True
```

Comment: Or better yet, use `functools.wraps` to preserve metadata of decorated function.

Comment: @thorhunter yes, though as far as I remember, `wraps` doesn't copy all attributes.

Comment: Ahhh, ok, so chaining decorators (wraps) produces wrapped wraps which is why I could not see t1. That makes much more sense now. Thank you.

Comment: @EliKorvigo is there a way to update such attribute? example I have in mind is a call counter. I tried few different things but couldn't manage to make it work